# Angular ng-click on inputed later on dom

Tags: events, click, angularjs

i'm changing a innter html of a dom element with a button. And when button is clicked i want to fire another controller function. Something like that. ... But is not working :).

```
$scope.addBtn = function() {
   $('domtarget').html('<button ng-click="removeButton();"></button>');
}

$scope.removeBtn = function() {
   $('domtarget').html('');
}
```

Please suggest fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not** modify DOM inside your controller, *ever*.

```
<div ng-show="showMe"></div>
<button ng-click="showMe = !showMe;anotherAction()">Switch</button>
<button ng-click="someOtherAction()">Switch2</button>
```

.

```
function SomeCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.showMe=true;
    $scope.anotherAction = function () {
        alert("gotcha");
    };
    $scope.someOtherAction = function () {
        $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;
        $scope.anotherAction();
    };
}
```

For hiding/showing an element conditionally, use [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) or [ng-hide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide).
For firing an event on click, use [ng-click](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick)